# How to center columns' headers?

Tags: tables

I am trying to do a table in latex and I need the headings to be aligned in the center and text in the left

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{The Goal Question Metric model}
\label{T:gqm}
\begin{tabular}{ p{2cm} p{11cm}  }
\toprule
 Metric & Statement\\
 \midrule
Purpose & Systematic literature review \\
Object & Peer review publications in computer science and software engineering \\
Issue & Task ranking approaches in software development \\
Viewpoint & Software engineers and industry practitioners \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! Try `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Metric} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Statement}`.

Comment: Note that in general these `H` placements are not recommened, they will come back and bite you at some point. It is better to learn to use floating tables properly.

Comment: I took a liberty and correct your question title that (at least me) be more clear what is your problem. If you not like this correction, please rever my correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested @imran in his comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{m}{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ p{2cm} p{11cm}  }
    \toprule
\mcc{Metric}& \mcc{Statement}  \\
    \midrule
Purpose     & Systematic literature review \\
Object      & Peer review publications in computer science and software engineering \\
Issue       & Task ranking approaches in software development \\
Viewpoint   & Software engineers and industry practitioners \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or by use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{The Goal Question Metric model}
\label{T:gqm}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} l X[l] @{}},
             row{1} = {c}
             }
    \toprule
Metric      & Statement     \\
    \midrule
Purpose     & Systematic literature review \\
Object      & Peer review publications in computer science and software engineering \\
Issue       & Task ranking approaches in software development \\
Viewpoint   & Software engineers and industry practitioners \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

where it is also ensured that the table does not protrude right text border:

[image]

**Note:**
Please always provide complete small document which reproduce your problem. From your code fragment for example we cannot extract information about used `\documentclass` nor  document layout. Both have influence on table looks out. For example, in the first MWE (Minimal Working Example) your table spill-out of right text border.

Comment: `\mcc` is not defined in your first code...

Comment: @F.Pantigny, you are right. Added now.

Answer (score 0):

Another  possibility uses the `\thead` command from `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\caption{The Goal Question Metric model}
\label{T:gqm}
\begin{tabular}{ p{2cm} p{11cm} }
\toprule
 \thead{Metric} & \thead{Statement}\\
 \midrule
Purpose & Systematic literature review \\
Object & Peer review publications in computer science and software engineering \\
Issue & Task ranking approaches in software development \\
Viewpoint & Software engineers and industry practitioners \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{The Goal Question Metric model}
\label{T:gqm}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{} l X[l] @{}}
    \toprule
\Block[c]{}{Metric}      & \Block[c]{}{Statement}     \\
    \midrule
Purpose     & Systematic literature review \\
Object      & Peer review publications in computer science and software engineering \\
Issue       & Task ranking approaches in software development \\
Viewpoint   & Software engineers and industry practitioners \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]